# cocoen slider in bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am working with a change slider library (cocoen)
https://github.com/koenoe/cocoen

it is working perfect but i want to use it in bootstrap carousal, if i use this approach:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cocoen').forEach(function(element){
  new Cocoen(element);
});
```

this will work with only first slider, after that i am trying inside the bootstrap carousal event like that:

```
$('#MySlider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                if($('#MySlider div.item').hasClass('active')) 
                {
                    new Cocoen(('#MySlider .cocoen'));

                }
            })
```

this is also not working, 
my carousel code:

```
 <div class="container">
            <div id="MySlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="cocoen">
                            <img src="images/before.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/after.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="cocoen">
                            <img src="images/before.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/after.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="cocoen">
                            <img src="images/before.jpg" alt="">
                            <img src="images/after.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#MySlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#MySlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

please guide me

Comment: Have you found a solution? The same thing happens to me in the slickcarousel

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue but I'm using Owl Carousel.

I've added this line to the `onDragStart()` method in the `cocoen.js` file:

```
this.dimensions();
```

and then each drag element takes the right position.

Hope it helps!